# FAILURE: Execution failed for task ':card.io:buildNative'

Tags: card.io

I downloaded cardio source and config follow First build guide. But when i run '`./gradlew build`', i got message like:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/media/hungnguyendata/eProtea/Projects/temp/card.io-Android-source/card.io/build.gradle' line: 163
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':SampleApp'.

  > A problem occurred configuring project ':card.io'.
  >   No such property: sonatypeUsername for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

After that, i create gradle.properties file for define property sonatypeUsername. Like this: "sonatypeUsername=sonatypeUsername
sonatypePassword=sonatypePassword". I got this message:

:card.io:buildNative
make: Entering directory `/Projects/temp/card.io-Android-source/card.io/src/main/jni'
make: *** No rule to make target`/Projects/temp/card.io-Android-source/card.io/src/main/jni/card.io-dmz/processor_support.cpp', needed by `/Projects/temp/card.io-Android-source/card.io/src/main/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/cardioDecider/card.io-dmz/processor_support.o'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: Leaving directory`/Projects/temp/card.io-Android-source/card.io/src/main/jni'
:card.io:buildNative FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':card.io:buildNative'.

> Process 'command '/home/hungnguyen/applications/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   
>   what should i do to build project. Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you please provide some more logging output?  Also, is this a duplicate of https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/issues/11 ?

Comment: @JeffBrateman thank you! I've updated with detail logging.